# python requests json response fails to print to console

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

> **What specific syntax must be changed in the code below in order for python3 to print out a meaningful error message that will enable us to diagnose the `203` response that is being returned by an API call?**

**ERROR MESSAGE:**

The error message that we are getting is as follows:

```
r.status_code is: 203
r.json() is:
r is:
<Response [203]>
3 ERROR: API call triggered the following exception:
b'Error Expecting value: line 3 column 1 (char 4)'
```

You can see that the error message is not meaningful because it fails to tell us enough about what is happening in order for us to be able to diagnose the problem.

**CODE THAT THROWS ERROR MESSAGE:**

The code that is triggering the above error output is as follows:

```
def createApiRequest(data, azdo_organization_name, azPAT, **inputVars):
  personal_access_token = ":"+azPAT
  headers = {}
  headers['Content-type'] = "application/json"
  headers['Authorization'] = b'Basic ' + base64.b64encode(personal_access_token.encode('utf-8'))
  api_version = "6.0-preview.4"
  url = ("https://dev.azure.com/%s/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints?api-version=%s" % (azdo_organization_name, api_version))
  r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)
  try:
    respCode = str(r.status_code)
    logString = "r.status_code is: " + respCode
    print(logString)
    logString = "r.json() is: "
    print(logString)
    print("r is: ")
    print(r)
    logString = r.json()
    print(logString)
  except Exception as e:
    logString = "3 ERROR: API call triggered the following exception:  "
    print(logString)
    logString = "Error {0}".format(str(e.args[0])).encode("utf-8")
    print(logString)
    exit(1)
  return respCode, r.json()
```

As you can see the code above is breaking on the line that asks it to print `r.json()` .

This code works when the API request does not return an error.

So this OP asks how to change the code so that meaningful information can be printed out to the console by python in cases when the response code is not ideal.

Comment: print ```r.content``` before the ```r.json()``` line -- that will show you the raw response prior to the [failed] json decoding.  many servers return invalid JSON if the request is not successful

Comment: @AbbeGijly That seems to work.  Thank you.  `r.content` returns a nasty mess that would take some time to format and analyze, but at least it returns something.